# Function to read, search a string and modify a txt file using php

Tags: php

I'm writing a php function which must open and read line by line the content of a txt file saved in the same directory of the php file and checks if the first value of the line is equal to a number which I give it as a parameter of the function and if this number isn't in the file I will create a new line with the number followed by another information separated by a space. This funcion is in a webhook file of a Facebook Messenger bot and it doesn't work if the function isn't commented out and I don't know why because I checked the code several times and I haven't found the error.
The code of the function is:

```
function messagesNumber($userid)
{
    $fo = ("url of the files", "a+");
    $found = false;
    if($fo) {
        $line = fgets($fo);
        while(! feof($fo) && $found == false) {
            $words = explode(" ", $line, 2);
            if($words[0] == $userid) {
                $found = true;
                $words[1] += 1;
                $messagges = $words [1];
                str_replace($line, $words, $fo);
            }
            $line = fgets($fo);
        }
        if(! $found) {
            fprintf($fo, "%d 1", $userid);
            $messages = 1;
        }
    }
    else
        $messagges = -1;
    fclose($fo);
    return $messagges;  
}
```

It returns: -1 if the file can't be open or an integer that coincides with the second number of every line.

It is an example of the txt file:

```
282318736127 5
827813487273 3
...
```

The first number is the id which Facebook assign to every user and the second number is a counter who counts how many messages a user writes to the bot and I increase this last number every times that a specific user sends a message to the bot.

Comment: `messages = 1;` that should have thrown you an undefined constant error, had you error reporting set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry I missed a "$" but the original code is correct. I have just edited the post

Comment: ... I always find that hard to believe ... did you retype it?

Comment: *"and it doesn't work if the function isn't commented out"* - I don't quite get what you mean here. Do you mean it works if you're not using that custom `messagesNumber()` function?

Comment: btw `$messagges` why the 2x `g`'s here? that another typo?

Comment: @cmorrissey yes, I tried to rewrite the code but the error persists

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes. If I delete the function from the webhook file, the bot works fine

Comment: so you're telling me that `$messages = 1;` is good yet in another instance that ` $messagges = -1;` is also good; right? TBH, I don't know where to throw myself here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- to many mistakes here

Comment: @cmorrissey yup. see my comment just above yours here

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm writing my original code calling the variables with italian names and I have translated it to publish the post and I have made some beating errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy ... your missing a `$`

```
if(! $found) {
    fprintf($fo, "%d 1", $userid);
    messages = 1; // missing $
}
```

to

```
if(! $found) {
    fprintf($fo, "%d 1", $userid);
    $messages = 1;
}
```

okay edit ...

easy your missing an `fopen`

```
$fo = ("url of the files", "a+");
```

to

```
$fo = fopen("url of the files", "a+");
```

Comment: I think you should go read the comment the OP left up there. and edited without marking it as an edit/mistake

Comment: sorry, I missed a "$" but the original code is correct. I have just edited the post

Comment: @GianlucaAcerbis edited to include another problem

Comment: omg I don't know how I missed it, thank you! Now the bot works fine!